# How to change the text of listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, text

I am creating a soundboard app and I use a `ListView` for voices. I want to change names because it uses the folder names now. Also I am new and I don't know english that good. Please help me.

This is my the code which one takes sound from raw:

```
MediaPlayer mp; 
Uri uri; 
ListView listView; 
TextView textBilgi; 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris); 
    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields(); 
    String[] mediaList = new String[fields.length]; 
    for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++) mediaList[count] =  fields[count].getName(); 
    textBilgi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBilgi1); 
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview); 
    ArrayAdapter<String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(giris.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mediaList); listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + ((TextView) view).getText(); 
    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop(); 
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(uri)); mp.start(); textBilgi.setText(((TextView) view).getText() + " [" + mp.getDuration() / 1000 + " sn.]"); } 
    });
```

I searched it and as I understand, I need a second `ListView`. Is there any other way?

Comment: which names? can you explain more

Comment: @AbdulKawee my code calls the voices from raw so the names are names of folders but I want to change them

Comment: I mean this is a soundboard so every button needs a different name, every list object